# How to improve MySQL join to be more efficient?

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization, longtable

I am trying to join table df1 with df2. The problem is that df2 is a very long table that have 40 million observations and I can't get the joined outcome in MySQL after waiting for more than 48 hours. So I want to ask if there is any way to improve the efficiency of this join. I already added an index on Tag column for both tables.

df1 and df2 have same structure and here is an example:

```
|Id        |Tag
| -------- | --------------------------------------------
|1         |c#
|1         |winforms
|1         |type-conversion
|1         |decimal
|2         |.net
|2         |decimal
|3         |.net
|3         |math
```

Both tables have two columns, Id and Tag. However, neither Id or Tag are uniquely identified keys. Only Id+Tag can be a uniquely identified key. What I need is to left out join df1 with df2 on column Tag. And here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE matched_outcome AS
SELECT df1.Id AS df1_Id, df2.Id AS df2_Id, COUNT(df2.Tag) AS overlapping
FROM df1
LEFT JOIN df2 ON df2.Tag=df1.Tag
GROUP BY df1.Id, df2.Id;
```

Comment: Add indexes on those columns.  That will help.  Before you do, run EXPLAIN PLAN and look for a table scan.  If you see one, you'll know adding the index will help.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry I forgot to mention before, I already added an index on Tag column for both tables.

Comment: 40 million rows?  You're screwed.  You need to filter on that big table to cut down the size of the JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

I would try composite index on (tag, id) for both tables in this order.

Check using execution plan if this index gets picked up.

Partitioning table on tag column *might* help, as partition internally creates multiple smaller tables.

Also you should run this and check where your process gets stuck
`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

That might give you further leads.

Answer (score 0):

"inflate-deflate syndrome" happens when you do `JOIN...GROUP BY`.  And it usually lead to wrong (high) values for aggregates (`COUNT`, `SUM`, etc).

I am too baffled about what the query is supposed to do to help you rewrite it.  Can you elaborate?  Why `LEFT`?  What is "overlapping"?

Sometimes the workaround is to do something like:

```
SELECT df1.some_stuff,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df2 WHERE Tag = df1.Tag ) AS overlapping
    FROM df1;
```

Does this even come close to what you want?

Comment: what I am actually trying to do is this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024037/how-to-merge-by-a-column-of-collection-using-python-pandas. Initially I was trying to use Python pandas proposed by the accepted answer. However, the last step (match df1 with df2) was problematic. So I decided to use MySQL to do the last step.

Comment: `<snide-remark>` Another case of 3rd party software getting in the way? `</snide-remark>`